# DynamicTableEntity PartitionKey and RowKey

Tags: c#, azure, dynamic-tables

I create DynamicTableEntity as follows:

```
string env = "envTest";
stting ver = "1.0";
siring id = "12356";
string mode = "verify";
DynamicTableEntity entryEntity = DynamicTableEntity(env,ver);
entryEntity.Properties.Add("Id", id);
entryEntity.Properties.Add("Mode", mode);
```

As a result created a table with columns:"Id", "Mode", "PartitionKey", "RowKey"
I want to change the names of "PartitionKey", "RowKey", i.e. I want the env to be a partitionKey but but The column name to be "Env". How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer is that you can't. `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` are system defined attributes (along with `Timestamp`) and you can't change their name. What you could do is define two more custom attributes for `Env` and `Ver` if you need to access the properties by these names in your application.

```
DynamicTableEntity entryEntity = DynamicTableEntity(env,ver);
entryEntity.Properties.Add("Id", id);
entryEntity.Properties.Add("Mode", mode);
entryEntity.Properties.Add("Env", env);
entryEntity.Properties.Add("Ver", ver);
```

Answer (score 7):

Although it's true that you can't rename PartitionKey and RowKey, you can resolve to a DTO straight from the table.

I find this super handy for projecting the data to different audiences (i.e limited view for non-admins etc)

HTH

```
var query = MyEntityDBO.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
            .Where(x => x.PartitionKey.Equals("Blah"))
            .Resolve(MyEntityDTO.GetEntityResolver());
var segment = await query.ExecuteSegmentedAsync(new TableContinuationToken());
if(segment.Results.Count > 0) {
     // Results = IEnumerable<MyEntityDTO>
}

public class MyEntityDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set;  }
    public string Env { get; set; }
    public string Ver { get; set; }

    public static EntityResolver<MyEntityDTO> GetEntityResolver()
    {
        return (pk, rk, ts, props, etag) =>
        { 
             Env = pk,
             Ver = rk,
             Id = props["Id"].StringValue,
             Mode = props["Mode"].StringValue
        };
    }
}
```